# Visual studio 2010 and kernel level programming!

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, kernel, device-driver

I have MS Visual Studio 2010 and I am planning to start kernel level & hardware driver programming..

Can i use MS Studio 2010 to do that? if, what exactly i need to add for that IDE?

In another way... what i need to do if i want to compile the following code in MS visual studio 2010? and what kind of project should i choose?

```
#define _X86_
#include "wdm.h"

NTSTATUS DriverEntry( IN PDRIVER_OBJECT theDriverObject,
IN PUNICODE_STRING theRegistryPath )
{
DbgPrint("Hello World!");
return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

***updated:*** thanks guys... what i need to add here
http://i56.tinypic.com/9jhw84.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the compiler and build scripts from the DDK.  You can use any IDE you like, as long as it can call the DDK build script.

EDIT: BTW, your code should not define `_X86_`.  The DDK build tool will define the right macros corresponding to the target version of Windows.

Comment: How i can do that (calling the DDK build script)... can you please explain the steps

Comment: @user630908:  Anyway, straightforward way to call the DDK build scripts from inside is with Tools -> External Tools, which allows you to add items to the Tools menu.  Set the command line to run the DDK build environment, and the working directory to use the variable representing your solution path.  Then you are only a couple clicks away from doing your build in the approved kernel build environment.  To make Intellisense work well, I recommend reading http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=186413

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [DDKBUILD.CMD](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=43) from OSR for years.  Here is an [article](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=104) that explains how to integrate it.  It's for an older version of Visual Studio, but the steps are just about the same for the VS2010.

Comment: I can confirm DDKBUILD.CMD works great with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) and do development along this path.  I don't believe you need to use the Visual Studio IDE (or should), but it's been a while since I investigated this information.  Here is a link that should get you started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428

Comment: Disagree. Visual C++ does everything you need in driver development except for debugging (and building by an external tool). If possible, using Visual C++ will help (as opposed to Notepad or another non-IDE editor).